# Two optional one-to-one EF relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, one-to-one

Is it possible to build two optional one-to-one relationship in SQL?

I'd like to have:

```
public class EventInvoice
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SZ_Event")]
        public Nullable<int> SZ_EventID { get; set; }
        public virtual SzopbudkaEvent SZ_Event { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UP_Event")]
        public Nullable<int> UP_EventID { get; set; }
        public virtual Event UP_Event { get; set; }
    }

public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    public virtual EventInvoice EventInvoice { get; set; }
} 

public class SzopbudkaEvent
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public virtual EventInvoice EventInvoice { get; set; }
    }
```

My invoice can be combined only with one of those objects (Event or SzopbudkaEvent). Is it possible to use it like this or I have to write something different?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but there are two things to bear in mond.

If the constraint is only one of the FK's can exist, then in the database the FK columns on the EventInvoice tale must be nullable. You've got this but I thought I'd emphasise it.

If there is also a constraint that there must be one of them (missing both is not allowed) then you have to work out how to validate that constraint. In the DB I'd use a trigger fir insert, update that raises an exception if both are null. I'd match that in code with a pre-save check: [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193959(v=vs.113).aspx) describes implementing interface IValidatableObject with a Validate method which EF will call when the object is affected by SaveChanges.

Comment: I'm getting this error why trying to do `add-migration`:
`One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

EventInvoice_Event_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'EventInvoice_Event_Source' in relationship 'EventInvoice_Event'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.` Same with `EventInvoice_SzopbudkaEvent_Source`

Comment: Can you add the DDL definition to your three tables by editing the question?

Comment: `EventInvoice Create`: https://pastebin.com/yf1w8RZu
`Event Create`: https://pastebin.com/mXpPQDcv
`Szopbudka Create`: https://pastebin.com/0VPpD24k
 This is for now, I'd like to edit it to code which I wrote above, because I added `SzopbudkaEvent` which can also have Invoice.

Comment: you should configure the inverse navigation properties, I don't really see why this setup would raise this exception, but mapping inverse navigation properties is always a lot cleaner.